# Chained async / await not working as intended

Tags: node.js

I'm migrating from promises to async/await and I'm having what I think is a strange issue. In the second function I'm getting that teams is undefined. Logging to the console I can see that the function InsertAgents is running before selectTeams finishes. What could be the issue?

```
    let selectTeams = function (){

                const request = new mssql.Request(pool);

                let query = `SELECT * from teams`;

                request.query(query, (err, result) => {

                    if (err === null) {
                        return result.recordset;

                    } else {
                        utils.logger.error(err);
                        reject(err);
                        console.log(err);
                    }

                })

        };

let insertAgents = function (params) {    
    console.log(params);
};

        const teams = await selectTeams();
        const agents = await insertAgents(teams);
```

Comment: It looks like you never defined `insertTeam`, and you also aren't using `selectTeams`

Comment: Your code now results in `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'selectTeams' has already been declared`

Comment: @CertainPerformance that was a typo...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)

Comment: `selectTeams` is not returning anything, so `await`ing it doesn't do anything (only try to use `await` on a Promise)

Answer (score 0):

make something in this way

```
function awaitablePromiseFunction(){
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

     asyncCallback = (response) => resolve(response)
   }
}

(async () => {
let waitfor = await awaitablePromiseFunction();
})()
```